# Which other feat might I use for double wielding reach?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, feats, weapons

Starting from the assumptions that Dragon Magazine material was often unbalanced (under- or over-powered) and that adding lots of options always increases the chance of combining powers and feats into something more lethal than otherwise, I gave my players a strict list of manuals they can use for character building.

I've always been prone to accept case-by-case additions from Dragon Magazines when it is a feat that fixes some problem with the rules, e.g. a class feature not working properly.

Now, one of my players is intent in creating a (level 10, bordering 11) character that looks like Kratos, from the God of War videogame franchise, and he would like to get the spiked chain training feat in order to be able to dual wield the chain.

Is there another feat that comes from the manuals (PHB 1 to 3, heroes of, * Power, forgotten realms campaign setting) that might make the character able to dual-wield reach weapons? I'm not against refluffing something else into a spiked chain.

Comment: Can you clarify what the player is looking for? Do they want to actually use powers that attack with both the main & offhand weapons? Or are they OK with a character who wields two weapons but all the powers use the main hand weapon only, and they just fluff it as attacking with both?

Comment: @ObliviousSage We made the character by now. Anyway, he wants to attack with both weapons, I think. I never played the game and I don't remeber if Kratos actually uses both chains to attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not until epic levels.**

Barring weapons that innately support dual-wielding and reach, there are *very* few ways to dual-wield 2-handed weapons (almost all reach weapons are 2-handed) or to gain reach.

The only always-on method of doing so that I'm aware of is the **Eternal Defender** epic destiny from Martial Power 1. Its level 24 feature, Godlike Stature, allows characters to wield weapons as if they were one size larger *and* increases their reach by 1 square.

The level 22 swordmage daily utility power **Giant's Might** from the Forgotten Realms Players Guide similarly increases the character's size and grants reach (but not the ability to wield larger weapons), but it only lasts for a single encounter.

Answer (score 0):

**You might be able to use a whip.**

The whip is a one-handed superior weapon with the reach & off-hand properties (though see below about off-hand). It was originally published in Dragon 368, but was also later included in the Dark Sun Campaign Setting & Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium books.

Dual-wielding whips is mechanically identical to wielding a spiked chain as a double weapon with the spiked chain training feat, with the following differences:

1. The damage drops from 2d4 to 1d4
2. The whips have to be enchanted separately rather than as a single double weapon (which costs more money but allows special properties on the off-hand weapon)
3. No feat is needed to dual-wield whips

*An Important Caveat:* As published in Dragon 368 and the Dark Sun CS the whip has the off-hand property. As published in Mordenkainen's Emporium it does *not* have that property. Neither book has received errata that resolves the discrepancy. It's thus ultimately up to the GM whether the whip has that property; if it doesn't, the ranger's ability to dual-wield non-off-hand weapons would be needed to dual-wield whips.

Comment: Nice and potentially useful for other people, but the whip is in none of the manuals I mentioned. I have no idea about manual primacy in D&D 4e but I guess later manuals errata out the earlier versions of the weapon.

Comment: @Zachiel You won't find any way to dual-wield reach weapons in any of those manuals. Well, I think there's an epic destiny and a swordmage daily utility that let you wield larger weapons (so you would be able to wield 2-hand weapons in 1 hand), but that's about it. 4e doesn't make it easy to get reach or to dual-wield 2-handed weapons (which is to say, all reach weapons other than the spiked chain & the whip). The whip is at least in non-Dragon material. As for manual primacy, in the rare cases when they reprint material with changes I *think* they usually errata the older version.

Comment: @Zachiel Actually the epic destiny I was thinking of is in Martial Power 1, so that's out as well. Basically, it's buy new books, allow Dragon material, or tell your player they can't dual-wield reach.

Comment: My fault. the * Power books are in. Editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you won't get the exact ability to Dual-Wield Spiked Chains, but if the character is fine with some 'reflavoring' of the weapon (and NOT reliant on other feats or powers that wants you specifically wielding that weapon) might I suggest the Transcendant Ki Focus, a Superior Implement.

> ***Transcendent Ki Focus**
>
>   Blinking (When you hit with a teleportation attack power, you have concealment until the start of your next turn.).
>
>   Reaching (You gain +1 reach with melee attacks using a reaching implement.).*

The character could then wield a different weapon, such as a Flail, that would mechanically be different but flavor/fluff could be changed. All that would be needed is obtaining Ki Focus Proficiency to take the **Superior Implement Training** feat.

**EDIT: This does not work by RAW, as PHB3 prevents Superior Implements from ever working with Weapons (regardless of the kind). So unless the Character is also deciding to go Monk, this won't work as I previously mentioned.**

Answer (score -1):

Mordenkaine's Magnificent Emporium page 21, Superior melee weapons, two-handed

> Spike Chain +3 proficiency, 2d4 damage, price 30gp, 10lb reach
>   property flail group

you would be looking at weapon proficiency spike chain feat and then flail feats for it.

Comment: The proficiency alone does not let you double-wield the weapon. You need the Spiked Chain Training feat, that I'm trying to replace.